# How to send an iCal meeting request using TransportBuilder in magento 2.x

Tags: php, email, magento2, icalendar

I want to integrate `iCal` meeting request with mail (in `magento 2.2.4 v` ). I am trying with following way but it doesn't work. Please help.

It shows as attachment in mail with `.bin` file

***TransportBuilder.php***

```
namespace Vendor\module\Magento\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder extends \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
{  


    const TYPE_TEXTCALENDER="text/calendar";

    public function addAttachment(
       $body,
       $filename    = null,
       $mimeType    = self::TYPE_TEXTCALENDER,
       $disposition = \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
       $encoding    = \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64
       ) {
         $this->message->createAttachment($body, $mimeType, $disposition, 
          $encoding, $filename);
           return $this;
      }
}
```

send mail code :-

```
.............
 $transport = $this->_transportBuilder- 
 >setTemplateIdentifier('template_identifier')
                        ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                        ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                        ->setFrom($from)
                        ->addTo($to)
                        ->addAttachment($ical)
                        ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
```

please check below link of sample ical file am using :-
https://gist.github.com/DeMarko/6142417

Comment: What exactly does not work with the given code? What happens instead?

Comment: Please check below link,  i want  same type of functionality but in magento 2.0 

http://www.julian-young.com/2009/07/07/php-ical-email/

Comment: As you've already posted some code, please tell us what is not working with the given code

Comment: **calendar event not added in mail**  it add as attachment file in received mail

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? What does `$ical` contain? Is the method to attach the file even called?

Comment: no i check the mail is received.
$ical is string of
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
.
.
.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR